# copy elements of arraylist in a set with the same order java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I've sorted an arraylist of int in ascending order, but when I copy it in a set, the elements are not sorted anymore.
I'm using this :

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(sortedArray);
```

why is like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet` will keep the order. `TreeSet` will sort based either on an external `Comparator` or natural ordering through `Comparable`.

A general point of a `Set` is that order is irrelevant. Hashing is intended to put the elements in as random an order as possible. `LinkedHashSet` maintains a linked-list between references to the elements, so can maintain an order.

`BitSet` (which is not a `Set`) may, or may not, provide a more efficient data structure.

Comment: but the method i'm implementing returns a set for my program (actually it's a uni project). and in this project i need to sort elements.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet's don't sort or maintain order, and the API will tell you this:

> it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Consider using another type of Set such as a TreeSet.

Comment: @NavidKoochooloo: you thought wrong. Please again read the quote from the HashSet API that I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about uniqueness, use the HashSet. If you're after sorting, then consider the TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and implement a Comparator object or Comparable interface for your data. you can read about Object ordering [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
hash set is designed for quick access to unique data, not for maintaining a particular order.